# Can't create free app service plan

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps, azure-app-services

I am trying to create a free linux app service plan. However ARM keeps telling me:

> This subscription has reached the limit of 1 Free Linux app service
> plan(s) it can create in this region. Please choose a different sku
> or region.

This however is misleading as there is not a single app service plan. Not a free one, none in the resource group nor in the whole subscription.

It's very likely that there **was** a free linux/windows based app service plan earlier, that got deleted at some point. Does Azure keep record of that?

Comment: Great that you solved you issue, but please post your answer as an answer instead of editing it into your question.

Comment: Please don't downvote without leaving a comment. What's wrong with this question please? I am investing time and also coming back with an answer that others might help, so what's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to raise a support ticket for this. If you do not have any active free plans then you should be able to create one, even if you had one before.

You can raise a billing support ticket for free, even if you don't have a support contract.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sam, I wasn't aware that filling billing tickets is free, but makes sense if I think about it :-) Will reach back with the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question.

I have one resource group called `rg-app-services` which is in `west europe`. That resource group holds the free app service plan for windows which is also in `west europe`.

Now there are a couple of limitations as listed here: [App Service on Linux and there Limitations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview#app-service-on-linux)

- App Service on Linux is not supported on Shared pricing tier.
- You can't mix Windows and Linux apps in the same App Service plan.
- Within the same resource group, you can't mix Windows and Linux apps in the same region.
- The Azure portal shows only features that currently work for Linux apps. As features are enabled, they're activated on the portal.
- When deployed to built-in images, your code and content are allocated a storage volume for web content, backed by Azure Storage. The disk latency of this volume is higher and more variable than the latency of the container filesystem. Apps that require heavy read-only access to content files may benefit from the custom container option, which places files in the container filesystem instead of on the content volume.

So long story short. I hade to create the free linux app service plan in another region and it worked! Still the error message is misleading, but hey learned something on the way...